# Typecast Error in C

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, buffer, structure

I have come across an Error that relates to typecasting in C. I have a structure, which is holding a float value called unioffs, and I need to take that float value into a buffer. For that I am using memcopy function.
Following is what I have implemented.

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((aligned (1), packed))
{
/*01 Bytes*/       uint8_t flags;  
/*01 Bytes*/       uint8_t store;               
/*04 Bytes*/       float unioffs;          /* detector offset in univalues default=0 */  
/*04 Bytes*/       float scale;            /* detector scale - default =1 */  
/*04 Bytes*/       float valalrm;          /* value alarm level - in univalue*/  
/*04 Bytes*/       float dosalrm;          /* dose alarm level - in unidose*/  
/*04 Bytes*/       float samperc;          /* percentage of the output sampled */  
/*04 Bytes*/       float dcstime;          /* time of the exposure in seconds  */  
/*03 Bytes*/       int8_t fillup[3];      /* !!!! allways fill up to 29 bytes */  

} DET_STUP;    


int main()  
{  
    DET_STUP det_stup[DET_NROFCHAN]; //NROFCHAN is #defined is 10  
    uint8_t response_to_LV[42];  
    memset(response_to_LV,0,42);  
    memset(guc_sensor_config_data,0,40);

    //guc_sensor_config_data is a global buffer of 40 bytes
    memcpy(guc_sensor_config_data+1*14,(float*)det_stup.unioffs,4);   

    //Further implementaions to send the buffer through UART  

}
```

The Error that I am getting here is: error#171: invalid type conversion

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a full compilable example please?  Including definitions for `DET_STUP`, `DET_NROFCHAN`, `guc_sensor_config_data` and `LEFT_CH`

Comment: What's the type of `det_stup[LEFT_CH].unioffs`? With the change to `det_stup.unioffs`, you'd get a "requesting member in something not a struct or union" or similar.

Comment: det_stup.unioffs is a float

Comment: No, `det_stup.unioffs` doesn't exist, since `det_stup` is an array. Anyway, you can't convert a `float` to a pointer. You need to take the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the address of (`&`) the `unioffs` field, and you need to provide the index of the DET_STUP in the array:

```
memcpy(guc_sensor_config_data+1*14, &det_stup[i].unioffs,4);
```

Comment: Lindback: I understand the intensions in having used the '&' operator. But why array index? What is 'i' here?

Comment: Check your declaration. What is this, a 0 length array? `DET_STUP det_stup[DET_NROFCHAN]; //NROFCHAN is #defined is 0`

Comment: You have to specify which of the 10 DET_STUP you want to copy unioff from.

Answer (score 0):

i think (float *) should be (char *) or use the address of det_stup.unioffs

Comment: (float*)&det_stup.unioffs   doesnt give any error/worning. but is that right??